# custom method in laravel 4.1 model not working

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use custom method in User model with class name User in laravel4.1. i changed the $table attribute to my table name and added a custom method names 'public function abc'  in user model. Then in my user controller i tried like this :-

`$u= new User;` 
`$u->abc();`

but its not working and giving  following error :-

BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::abc()

and i dnt know why this happening everything seems fine,help me out in this guys.

UPDATE :SOLVED ,Done Nothing
I DO NOT KNOW WHAT IS THE PROBLEM WITH LARAVEL
`$u= new user;` 
`$u->abc();`

i just changed User to user and its started working and i dnt even know why ,anyone know reason??

Comment: Can we see your actual model class?

Comment: You should be using `User::abc()`.

Comment: @user2094178 No, his function is an instance method, not static.

Comment: Ok, I noticed methods from packages are invoked as such even they are not static, but that must be the collateral of a Facade.

Comment: For some reason, it's instantiating an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`.  Try using `$u= new \User;`

Answer (score 0):

Every method on a Model get passed on to a new QueryBuilder

```
User::where()
User::find()
User::{relationship}()
```

If you instantiate a model like this

```
$user = User::find()->method();
```

it will work. Don't try to make your Eloquent models too fat. 
Just create a Repository to make your Controllers as thin as possible and your Eloquent just as intelligent as it can be by using the tools given by Eloquent (relationships, hidden attributes, accessors & mutators, $this->appends, ...)

Everything else belongs in your Repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
composer dumpautoload
```

If this doesn't work, be sure that there  is only one class called User in your whole project. There may be a package, migration or something with the same name. Try putting your custom User class in a namespace.